# Using Ionic - Cannot get Firebase to load properly - Error: Module 'firebase' is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

I have looked at the following questions and have not been able to find an effective solution, hence I am posting another question.

[Ionic + firebase, error Module 'firebase' is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26950839/ionic-firebase-error-module-firebase-is-not-available)

[Firebase, AngularFire Error: Module firebase is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25021003/firebase-angularfire-error-module-firebase-is-not-available)

[Angularfire 'Firebase' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25021640/angularfire-firebase-is-not-defined)

I am very much a beginner and this is my first Ionic app using Firebase. I am simply trying to get Firebase to load properly. I have included the following CDNs in my index.html:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

<!--firebase-->
     <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
<!--angularfire-->
     <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.0.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js:**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'firebase', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])



.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }


  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'tab-login': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.new', {
    url: '/new',
    views: {
      'tab-new': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-new.html',
        controller: 'NewCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.home', {
      url: '/home',
      views: {
        'tab-home': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-home.html',
          controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }
      }
    })


  .state('tab.profile', {
    url: '/profile',
    views: {
      'tab-profile': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-profile.html',
        controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/home');

});
```

**controller.js:**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic', 'firebase', 'starter.services'])


.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope) {


})

.controller('NewCtrl', function($scope) {})

.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, Chats) {
  $scope.chats = Chats.all();
  $scope.remove = function(chat) {
    Chats.remove(chat);
  }
})



.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    enableFriends: true
  };
});
```

With this code, I get the errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(anonymous function) @ angularfire.min.js:12(anonymous function) @ angularfire.min.js:12
ionic.bundle.js:8762 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module firebase due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'firebase' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/nomod?p0=firebase
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8762:12)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10466:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10390:38)
    at module (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10464:14)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:12796:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9022:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:12780:5)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:12797:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9022:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:12780:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=firebase&p1=Error%…%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8100%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A12780%3A5)
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8762:12)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:12819:15
    at forEach (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9022:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:12780:5)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:12797:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9022:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:12780:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:12706:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10144:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10165:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=starter&p1=Error%3…3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8100%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A10165%3A12)
```

I did not include the angular CDN because ionic includes it.
I already created a new app on firebase, and can access it through the firebase dashboard.

Any ideas how to get firebase up and running correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move `ionic.bundle.js` before `angularfire.min.js`, Because angular fire.js using angular object while creating module & it is throwing an error.

Comment: Maybe Angular is included in this bundle `<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>`, if so he just needs to move it above his reference to `angularfire.min.js`

Comment: @azium thanks for heads up...I just updated an answer